# static binding with new operator c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, static-binding

i want to be sure if i understand that corectly. If i have something like that:

```
Base* wsk = new Derived
```

and if i've done that with static-binding than wsk is type of Base, but Derived type object is still created? And `wsk` is pointing to that Derived type object, but it cannot use methods from derived class, because `wsk` is Base type? To sum up the most important question for me is that if `wsk` except that it's Base type is still pointing to new object which is Derived type?

Comment: Yes, it points to a `Derived` but you can only use `Derived` members after casting to `Derived`. I feel like any good C++ book or tutorial would make this clear pretty early.

Comment: Of course any virtual methods that exist in `Derived` can be used without casting.

Comment: @john "any virtual methods of `Base` that `Derived` overrides"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wsk` is of type `Base *`, not `Base` nor `Derived`.

It was initialised with a value that was (implicitly) converted from type `Derived *`. It points to a `Base` object, which so happens to reside within a `Derived` object.

That means that `static_cast<Derived *>(wsk)` will give you a value that points to a `Derived`.

It may be that the *representation* of `wsk` is the same number as the *representation* of `static_cast<Derived *>(wsk)`, i.e. that the address of the `Base` object is the same as the address of the `Derived` object, but that is not guaranteed

Comment: *It points to a Base object, which so happens to reside within a Derived object.* - wsk (here) points to an object of type Derived.

Comment: @Swordfish No, it points to the `Base` base sub-object of a `Derived` object

Comment: There is no "sub-object". If you wish to argue in that direction bring reference.

Comment: @Swordfish "Each direct and indirect base class is present, as base class subobject, within the object representation of the derived class at implementation-defined offset." [derived class on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class)

Comment: @Swordfish Consider multiple inheritance and virtual base classes: if every derived instance always had the same address as its base, those would simply not be possible.

Comment: @Swordfish or "Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject ([class.mem]), a base class subobject ([class.derived]), or an array element." [`[intro.object]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#2)

Answer (score 3):

*One big remark, as mentioned above, when looking at `Base *` it point to type `Base`. I'm not using this notation in order to simplify the explanation.*

What you are asking is a different question: what is the difference between the **static type** and the **dynamic/runtime type** of an object.

Let's observe the following code:

```
#import <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "From Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class A : public Base
{
    public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "From A" << std::endl;
    }

    void some_A_only_function()
    {
        std::cout << "some function from A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "From B" << std::endl;
    }

    void some_B_only_function()
    {
        std::cout << "some function from B" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Base base{};
    Base * a = new A();
    Base * b = new B();

    base.foo();

    a->foo();
    // a->some_A_only_function(); this won't compile: error: no member named 'some_A_only_function' in 'Base'

    b->foo();
    // b->some_B_only_function(); this won't compile either!!
}
```

And the output is:

> From Base
>
> From A
>
> From B

All the objects here are from a static type of `Base`, thus, you cannot call any function that isn't part of `Base`, since the compiler **cannot** know which type is put in there in runtime. If we have overridden functions, the appropriate one will be called according to the runtime type (this is called ***dynamic dispatch***).

To sum it up, there are 3 objects here:

1. An object of static type `Base` and dynamic type `Base`.
2. An object of static type `Base` and dynamic type `A`.
3. An object of static type `Base` and dynamic type `B`.

The only way to use the functions of `A` or `B` respectively, is by using casting in order to *"return"* them into their original form. But it should be done with caution!

**Big remark:** This is actually true in any language that offers polymorphism (as far as I know). It isn't unique to C++!

Comment: Nitpick: there are also 2 objects of type `Base *`, and there were materialised temporaries of type `A *` and `B *`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed I have made over-simplification in order to address the core of the question, added a comment about that :)

Comment: @Kerek i'm still thinking that my question is correct, but your answer help to clarify that what Caleth is mentioned. Thanks for that.